# Tuple of stream vs stream of tuples in arrowized FRP

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming

Most reactive programming seem to revolve around the concept of a Behaviour or a signal which is defined as:

```
Behaviour a = T -> a
```

In arrowized FRP this abstraction is hidden behind a Signal Function of type

```
SF a b = Behaviour a -> Behaviour b
```

My question is regarding the type `SF a b`.

Imagine I have a type `SF (a,b) c` this would represent a signal function which accepts a tuple `(a,b)` as input and returns the type `c` as output. Which implies a stream of tuples. But how then do we distinguish this type with tuple of stream? Imagine having something like

```
(Behaviour a, Behaviour b) -> Behaviour c
```

this is not equivalent to `SF (a,b) c`, then what combinators do we have in  arrowized FRP to represent tuple of streams and their associated operations?

Comment: If you are asking about the semantic domain in which `Behavior a = T -> a`, it might be an informative exercise to try to define an isomorphism between `Behavior (a,b)` and `(Behavior a, Behavior b)`

Comment: We can have `zip :: (Behaviour a, Behaviour b) -> Behaviour (a,b)` and `unzip :: Behaviour (a, b) -> (Behaviour a, Behaviour b)` s.t `zip . unzip = id`, however while this works for defining the semantics I wonder in practise while working with arrowized FRP how would a user actually talk about `(Behaviour a, Behaviour b)` as these types are not exposed in the first place.

Comment: Right, you don't -- you talk about `SF (a,b) c` instead. Because this isomorphism exists, there is not loss of expressivity.